# angular.js rerender div after model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select with

```
ng-model="vm.selectedUserId"
```

and somewhere on the page I have

```
  .table-responsive(ng-if="vm.selectedUserId")
    %time-tracking-calendar( user-id="vm.selectedUserId" company-id="vm.companyId")
```

The thing is: I want the .table-responsive block to be rerendered without touching the directive when the vm.selectedUserId changes. My current solution is to have

```
  .table-responsive(ng-if="vm.selectedUserId && vm.showCalendar")
    %time-tracking-calendar( user-id="vm.selectedUserId" company-id="vm.companyId")
```

and

```
$scope.$watch('vm.selectedUserId', function() {
  vm.showCalendar = false;
  $timeout(function() {
    vm.showCalendar = true;
  }, 100);
});
```

in the controller, but it looks way too dirty for me. Is there a more elegant solution (except the obvious one of watching the userId variable inside the directive) ?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had written a directive for exactly similar purpose

```
csapp.directive("csReloadOn", ["$timeout", "$log", function ($timeout, $log) {

    var getTemplate = function () {
        return '<div ng-if="doRefreshPageOnModeChange"><div ng-transclude=""></div></div>';
    };

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true;

        scope.$watch(attrs.csReloadOn, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal === oldVal) return;
            $log.info("changed mode from : " + oldVal + ", to : " + newVal);
            scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = false;
            $timeout(function () { scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true; }, 100);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: getTemplate,
        link: linkFunction
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try tomorrow in the office. (I think it's the same what ui-if was for in the older versions of angular)